# Why gevent can speed up requests to download?

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent

I think `requests.get` should be block, so there should be no difference between run and run2.

```
import sys

import gevent
import requests
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
def download():
    requests.get('http://www.baidu.com').status_code
def run():
    ls = [gevent.spawn(download) for i in range(100)]
    gevent.joinall(ls)
def run2():
    for i in range(100):
        download()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer(stmt="run();", setup="from __main__ import run")
    print('good', t.timeit(3))
    t = Timer(stmt="run2();", setup="from __main__ import run2")
    print('bad', t.timeit(3))
    sys.exit(0)
```

but result is:

```
good 5.006664161000117
bad 29.077525214999696
```

so are there all kind read, write could be speed up by gevent?

PS: I run it on mac/python3/requests 2.10.0/gevent 1.1.2

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `gevent`, but I'd imagine it's due to I/O. When you make a web request, there's the overhead of establishing a connection with the server, making the handshake, etc. A lot of this ends up idle time during which the client is waiting for a response. While it's idle, `gevent` most likely sends out other requests. The Python-only implementation, though, will wait for each request to complete before sending out another.

Comment: that make sense,so r`equests.get` not block all the time,part of his job are replace by gevent which can do something else if block.
the point is how much `gevent` can change `requests`,for example,he can change almost all `urllib`.so that is much faster than requests.

Answer (score -1):

From the [gevent website](http://gevent.org):

> Fast event loop based on libev (epoll on Linux, kqueue on FreeBSD).
>
> Lightweight execution units based on greenlet.
>
> API that re-uses concepts from the Python standard library (for example there are gevent.event.Events and gevent.queue.Queues).
>
> Cooperative sockets with SSL support
>
> DNS queries performed through threadpool or c-ares.
>
> Monkey patching utility to get 3rd party modules to become cooperative

Basically, just `for` looping a bunch of `requests.get()` calls is slow due to the fact that you're, well, `for` looping through a bunch of `requests.get()` calls. Gevent'ing a bunch of `requests.get()` calls isn't slow due to the fact that you're throwing those calls into a threaded Queue instead, which then uses gevent's powerful API to run through those calls incredibly efficiently.

Comment: en,i know what your meaning.but`you're throwing those calls into a threaded Queue instead`, that not change anything if job is block, one time do one job, and the job is "sleep to wait" !!! nobody move untill he's work done.

Comment: In your example, blocking doesn't actually affect anything. You're only `requests.get()`ing. Really. So, the Thread `Queue` fires off as many of those jobs as gevent/your processor will allow.

Now, if you were having that modify a variable (say, a string value based on page text), blocking would definitely come into play there due to the GIL.